# how to multiply and sum from 3 to 6 button on pycharm python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning to make an app using python and tkinter.
and i was made a resistor calculator. the question is how to calculate the multiplication and addition of several buttons to get the value and write the total results in the resistor value entrybox?

and the worse, I don't know how to write the code here. so I gave the link.

thank you so much

[enter link description here](https://www10.zippyshare.com/v/BT66aGHQ/file.html)

```
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk

class Resistor:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Roghib Calculator Resistor")
        self.root.geometry("1000x560+0+0")
        self.root.configure(background="aqua")

        var1 = IntVar()
        var2 = IntVar()
        var3 = IntVar()
        var4 = IntVar()
        var5 = IntVar()
        var6 = IntVar()
        var7 = IntVar()
        var8 = IntVar()
        var9 = IntVar()

        var1.set("")
        var2.set("")
        var3.set("")
        var4.set("")
        var5.set("")
        var6.set("")
        var7.set("")
        var8.set("")
        var9.set("")

        #value 1stband
        def Band1b():
            var1.set(10)
        def Band1c():
            var1.set(20)
        def Band1d():
            var1.set(30)
        def Band1e():
            var1.set(40)
        def Band1f():
            var1.set(50)
        def Band1g():
            var1.set(60)
        def Band1h():
            var1.set(70)
        def Band1i():
            var1.set(80)
        def Band1j():
            var1.set(90)




        #value 2ndband
        def Band2a():
            var2.set(0)
        def Band2b():
            var2.set(1)
        def Band2c():
            var2.set(2)
        def Band2d():
            var2.set(3)
        def Band2e():
            var2.set(4)
        def Band2f():
            var2.set(5)
        def Band2g():
            var2.set(6)
        def Band2h():
            var2.set(7)
        def Band2i():
            var2.set(8)
        def Band2j():
            var2.set(9)

        def hitung():
            var1 = var1.get()
            var2 = var2.get()

        def quit():
            quit = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('Calculator Resistor', 'yakin arep metu?')
            if quit > 0:
                root.destroy()
                return

        def reset():
            reset = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('Calculator Resistor', 'yakin arep reset ?')
            if reset > 0:
                var1.set("")
                return

        #frame = Frame(root)
        #frame.grid()

        mainFrame = Frame(self.root, bg='olive')
        mainFrame.grid()

        TitleFrame = Frame(mainFrame, bg='yellow', bd=10, width=1320, padx=10, relief=RIDGE)
        TitleFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.lblTitle = Label(TitleFrame, bg='yellow', font=('times new roman', 50, 'bold'), text="Calculator Resistor", padx=200)
        self.lblTitle.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ResistorFrame = Frame(mainFrame, bd=10, width=1350, padx=20, bg='dimgrey', relief=RIDGE)
        ResistorFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        IndicatorFrame = Frame(mainFrame, bg='yellow', bd=10, width=1350, padx=10, relief=RIDGE)
        IndicatorFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        #===============================================label Band Title===================================================

        self.lblTitle = Label(ResistorFrame, bg="orangered", width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'),text="1st Band")
        self.lblTitle.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.lblTitle = Label(ResistorFrame, bg="orangered", width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text="2nd Band")
        self.lblTitle.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.lblTitle = Label(ResistorFrame, bg="orangered", width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text="3rd Band")
        self.lblTitle.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.lblTitle = Label(ResistorFrame, bg="orangered", width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text="4th Band")
        self.lblTitle.grid(row=1, column=3)
        self.lblTitle = Label(ResistorFrame, bg="orangered", width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text="5th Band")
        self.lblTitle.grid(row=1, column=4)
        self.lblTitle = Label(ResistorFrame, bg="orangered", width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text="6th Band")
        self.lblTitle.grid(row=1, column=5)

        #option total Band
        self.dis = Radiobutton(ResistorFrame, text="3 Band", font='bold', value=0, bg='dimgrey', command=self.enable_band3)
        self.dis.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.en = Radiobutton(ResistorFrame, text="6 Band", font='bold', value=1, bg='dimgrey', command=self.disable_band3)
        self.en.grid(column=4, row=0)
        self.dis4 = Radiobutton(ResistorFrame, text="4 Band", font='bold', value=2, bg='dimgrey', command=self.enable_band4)
        self.dis4.grid(column=2, row=0)
        self.en4 = Radiobutton(ResistorFrame, text="5 Band", font='bold', value=3, bg='dimgrey', command=self.disable_band4)
        self.en4.grid(column=3, row=0)


        #1st Band
        self.Band1a = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='0', fg='white', bg='black')
        self.Band1a.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.Band1b = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band1b, text='1', fg='black', bg='peru')
        self.Band1b.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.Band1c = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band1c, text='2', fg='black', bg='red')
        self.Band1c.grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.Band1d = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band1d, text='3', fg='black', bg='orange')
        self.Band1d.grid(row=5, column=0)
        self.Band1e = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band1e, text='4', fg='black', bg='yellow')
        self.Band1e.grid(row=6, column=0)
        self.Band1f = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band1f, text='5', fg='black', bg='green')
        self.Band1f.grid(row=7, column=0)
        self.Band1g = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band1g, text='6', fg='black', bg='blue')
        self.Band1g.grid(row=8, column=0)
        self.Band1h = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band1h, text='7', fg='black', bg='purple')
        self.Band1h.grid(row=9, column=0)
        self.Band1i = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band1i, text='8', fg='black', bg='dimgrey')
        self.Band1i.grid(row=10, column=0)
        self.Band1j = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band1j, text='9', fg='black', bg='white')
        self.Band1j.grid(row=11, column=0)

        #2nd Band
        self.Band2a = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band2a, text='0', fg='white', bg='black')
        self.Band2a.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.Band2b = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), command=Band2b, text='1', fg='black', bg='peru')
        self.Band2b.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.Band2c = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='2', fg='black', bg='red')
        self.Band2c.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.Band2d = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='3', fg='black', bg='orange')
        self.Band2d.grid(row=5, column=1)
        self.Band2e = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='4', fg='black', bg='yellow')
        self.Band2e.grid(row=6, column=1)
        self.Band2f = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='5', fg='black', bg='green')
        self.Band2f.grid(row=7, column=1)
        self.Band2g = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='6', fg='black', bg='blue')
        self.Band2g.grid(row=8, column=1)
        self.Band2h = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='7', fg='black', bg='purple')
        self.Band2h.grid(row=9, column=1)
        self.Band2i = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='8', fg='black', bg='dimgrey')
        self.Band2i.grid(row=10, column=1)
        self.Band2j = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='9', fg='black', bg='white')
        self.Band2j.grid(row=11, column=1)

        #3rd Band
        self.Band3a = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='0', fg='white', bg='black')
        self.Band3a.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.Band3b = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='1', fg='black', bg='peru')
        self.Band3b.grid(row=3, column=2)
        self.Band3c = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='2', fg='black', bg='red')
        self.Band3c.grid(row=4, column=2)
        self.Band3d = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='3', fg='black', bg='orange')
        self.Band3d.grid(row=5, column=2)
        self.Band3e = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='4', fg='black', bg='yellow')
        self.Band3e.grid(row=6, column=2)
        self.Band3f = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='5', fg='black', bg='green')
        self.Band3f.grid(row=7, column=2)
        self.Band3g = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='6', fg='black', bg='blue')
        self.Band3g.grid(row=8, column=2)
        self.Band3h = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='7', fg='black', bg='purple')
        self.Band3h.grid(row=9, column=2)
        self.Band3i = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='8', fg='black', bg='dimgrey')
        self.Band3i.grid(row=10, column=2)
        self.Band3j = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='9', fg='black', bg='white')
        self.Band3j.grid(row=11, column=2)

        #4th Band
        self.Band4a = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='x1', fg='white', bg='black')
        self.Band4a.grid(row=2, column=3)
        self.Band4b = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='x10', fg='black', bg='peru')
        self.Band4b.grid(row=3, column=3)
        self.Band4c = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='x100', fg='black', bg='red')
        self.Band4c.grid(row=4, column=3)
        self.Band4d = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='x1k', fg='black', bg='orange')
        self.Band4d.grid(row=5, column=3)
        self.Band4e = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='x10k', fg='black', bg='yellow')
        self.Band4e.grid(row=6, column=3)
        self.Band4f = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='x100k', fg='black', bg='green')
        self.Band4f.grid(row=7, column=3)
        self.Band4g = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='x1M', fg='black', bg='blue')
        self.Band4g.grid(row=8, column=3)
        self.Band4h = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='x10M', fg='black', bg='purple')
        self.Band4h.grid(row=9, column=3)
        self.Band4a = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='x0.01', fg='black', bg='darkgray')
        self.Band4a.grid(row=10, column=3)
        self.Band4b = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='x0.1', fg='black', bg='darkgoldenrod')
        self.Band4b.grid(row=11, column=3)

        #5thband
        self.Band5a = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='1%', fg='black', bg='peru')
        self.Band5a.grid(row=3, column=4)
        self.Band5b = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='2%', fg='black', bg='red')
        self.Band5b.grid(row=4, column=4)
        self.Band5c = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='0.5%', fg='black', bg='green')
        self.Band5c.grid(row=7, column=4)
        self.Band5d = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='0.25%', fg='black', bg='blue')
        self.Band5d.grid(row=8, column=4)
        self.Band5e = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='0.1%', fg='black', bg='purple')
        self.Band5e.grid(row=9, column=4)
        self.Band5g = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='10%', fg='black', bg='darkgray')
        self.Band5g.grid(row=10, column=4)
        self.Band5f = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='5%', fg='black', bg='darkgoldenrod')
        self.Band5f.grid(row=11, column=4)
        #6th Band
        self.Band6a = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='250ppm/K', fg='white', bg='black')
        self.Band6a.grid(row=2, column=5)
        self.Band6b = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='100ppm/K', fg='black', bg='peru')
        self.Band6b.grid(row=3, column=5)
        self.Band6c = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='50ppm/K', fg='black', bg='red')
        self.Band6c.grid(row=4, column=5)
        self.Band6d = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='15ppm/K', fg='black', bg='orange')
        self.Band6d.grid(row=5, column=5)
        self.Band6e = Button(ResistorFrame, width=8, font=('times new roman', 14, 'bold'), text='25ppm/K', fg='black', bg='yellow')
        self.Band6e.grid(row=6, column=5)

        #Indicator Frame
        self.lblFirst = Label(IndicatorFrame, bg='yellow', font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), text="Resistor Value")
        self.lblFirst.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)
        self.txtFirst = Entry(IndicatorFrame, width=16, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), textvariable=var1)
        self.txtFirst.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=3, columnspan=3)
        self.lbltole = Label(IndicatorFrame, bg='yellow', font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), text="Tolerance")
        self.lbltole.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)
        self.txtSecond = Entry(IndicatorFrame, width=16, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), textvariable=var8)
        self.txtSecond.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=3)
        self.temp = Label(IndicatorFrame, bg='yellow', font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), text="Temp. Coefficient")
        self.temp.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)
        self.txtthird = Entry(IndicatorFrame, width=16, font=('times new roman', 15, 'bold'), textvariable=var8)
        self.txtthird.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=5)

        btnQuit = Button(IndicatorFrame, height=2, text="QUIT", width=8, command=quit)
        btnQuit.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=10)
        btnReset = Button(IndicatorFrame, height=2, text="RESET", command=reset, width=8)
        btnReset.grid(column=2, row=3, pady=10)
        btnHitung = Button(IndicatorFrame, height=2, command=hitung, text="HITUNG", width=8)
        btnHitung.grid(column=3, row=3, pady=10)

    def enable_band3(self):
        if self.en == 0:
            self.Band3a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3b.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3c.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3d.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3e.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3f.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3g.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3h.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3i.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3j.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5b.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5c.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5d.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5e.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5f.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5g.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6b.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6c.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6d.configure(state='normal')
        else:
            self.Band1a.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3a.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3b.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3c.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3d.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3e.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3f.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3g.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3h.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3i.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3j.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band5a.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band5b.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band5c.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band5d.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band5e.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band5f.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band5g.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6a.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6b.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6c.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6d.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6e.configure(state='disabled')

    def disable_band3(self):
        if self.dis != 0:
            self.Band1a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3b.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3c.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3d.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3e.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3f.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3g.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3h.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3i.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3j.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5b.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5c.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5d.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5e.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5f.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5g.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6b.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6c.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6d.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6e.configure(state='normal')

    def enable_band4(self):
        if self.en4 == 1:
            self.Band3a.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3b.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3c.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3d.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3e.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3f.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3g.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3h.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3i.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3j.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6a.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6b.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6c.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6d.configure(state='disabled')
        else:
            self.Band3a.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3b.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3c.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3d.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3e.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3f.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3g.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3h.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3i.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band3j.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band5a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5b.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5c.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5d.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5e.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5f.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5g.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6a.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6b.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6c.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6d.configure(state='disabled')

    def disable_band4(self):
        if self.dis4 != 1:
            self.Band1a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3b.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3c.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3d.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3e.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3f.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3g.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3h.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3i.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band3j.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5b.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5c.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5d.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5e.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5f.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band5g.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6a.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6b.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6c.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6d.configure(state='normal')
            self.Band6a.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6b.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6c.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6d.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Band6e.configure(state='disabled')

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Tk()
    application = Resistor(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please learn how to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here if you want people to help as people won't be inclined to click a random link.

Comment: put code in question and use button `{}` to format it.

Comment: Post relevant code, highlight it, and press `Ctrl + K`

Comment: When you start to add digits to your variable names over and over again then something is wrong and you should use an appropriate datastructure (list, dictionary, ...) instead.

Comment: you should keep all `IntVar()` and buttons on lists and then you could use `for`-loop to make code much shorter.

Comment: in all functions where you run `varX.set()` you should execute the same function which calculate values from all `varX` and set text in `Label/Entry` (instead of using `textvariable=varX`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In functions `SetBand` after `varX.set()` you can execute function which calculate value and update it in Entry.

---

Other changes (which reduced lines of code):

I keep colors and buttons text on lists so I can use `for`-loop (with `zip()` and `enumerate()`) to generate buttons. I keep buttons on list so later I can use `for`-loop to change states in buttons.

In `command=` I use `lamba` so I can assign the same function with different arguments

---

Full working code but I'm not sure if all works as expected.

```
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Resistor:

    def set_band1(self, value):
        self.var_band1.set(value)
        self.update_labels()

    def set_band2(self, value):
        self.var_band2.set(value)
        self.update_labels()

    def set_band3(self, value):
        self.var_band3.set(value)
        self.update_labels()

    def set_band4(self, value):
        self.var_band4.set(value)
        self.update_labels()

    def set_band5(self, value):
        self.var_band5.set(value)
        self.update_labels()

    def set_band6(self, value):
        self.var_band6.set(value)
        self.update_labels()

    def update_labels(self):
        v1 = self.var_band1.get()*100
        v2 = self.var_band2.get()*10
        v3 = self.var_band3.get()*1
        value = (v1+v2+v3) * self.var_band4.get()
        self.var_resistance.set(value)

        value = self.var_band5.get()
        self.var_tolerance.set(value)

        value = self.var_band6.get()
        self.var_temp.set(value)

    def hitung(self):
        var1 = self.var_band1.get()
        var2 = self.var_band2.get()

    def quit(self):
        result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('Calculator Resistor', 'yakin arep metu?')
        if result:
            root.destroy()

    def reset(self):
        result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('Calculator Resistor', 'yakin arep reset ?')
        if result:
            self.var_band1.set(0)


    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Roghib Calculator Resistor")
        #self.root.geometry("1000x560+0+0")
        self.root.configure(background="aqua")

        self.var_band1 = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.var_band2 = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.var_band3 = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.var_band4 = tk.IntVar(value=1)

        self.var_band5 = tk.StringVar(value='')
        self.var_band6 = tk.StringVar(value='')

        self.var_resistance = tk.StringVar(value='0')
        self.var_tolerance = tk.StringVar(value='0')
        self.var_temp = tk.StringVar(value='0')

        # === Frames ===

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='olive')
        main_frame.grid()

        title_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg='yellow', bd=10, width=1320, padx=10, relief='ridge')
        title_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.lblTitle = tk.Label(title_frame, bg='yellow', font=('times new roman', 50, 'bold'), text="Calculator Resistor", padx=200)
        self.lblTitle.grid(row=0, column=0)

        resistor_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bd=10, width=1350, padx=20, bg='dimgrey', relief='ridge')
        resistor_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')

        indicator_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg='yellow', bd=10, width=1350, padx=10, relief='ridge')
        indicator_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')

        # === label Band Title ===

        FONT1 = ('times new roman', 14, 'bold')
        FONT2 = ('times new roman', 15, 'bold')

        for i, name in enumerate(('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th')):
            label = tk.Label(resistor_frame, text="{} Band".format(name), bg="orangered", width=8, font=FONT1)
            label.grid(row=1, column=i)

        #option total Band

        options = {'font': 'bold', 'bg': 'dimgrey'}

        self.dis  = tk.Radiobutton(resistor_frame, text="3 Band", value=0, command=self.enable_band3, **options)
        self.dis.grid(column=1, row=0)

        self.dis4 = tk.Radiobutton(resistor_frame, text="4 Band", value=2, command=self.enable_band4, **options)
        self.dis4.grid(column=2, row=0)

        self.en4  = tk.Radiobutton(resistor_frame, text="5 Band", value=3, command=self.disable_band4, **options)
        self.en4.grid(column=3, row=0)

        self.en   = tk.Radiobutton(resistor_frame, text="6 Band", value=1, command=self.disable_band3, **options)
        self.en.grid(column=4, row=0)

        colors_1  = (
            ('white', 'black'),
            ('black', 'peru'),
            ('black', 'red'),
            ('black', 'orange'),
            ('black', 'yellow'),
            ('black', 'green'),
            ('black', 'blue'),
            ('black', 'purple'),
            ('black', 'dimgrey'),
            ('black', 'white'),
        )

        colors_2  = (
            ('white', 'black'),
            ('black', 'peru'),
            ('black', 'red'),
            ('black', 'orange'),
            ('black', 'yellow'),
            ('black', 'green'),
            ('black', 'blue'),
            ('black', 'purple'),
            ('black', 'darkgray'),
            ('black', 'darkgoldenrod'),
        )

        # === 1st Band ===

        self.buttons_band1 = []

        for i, color in enumerate(colors_1):
            button = tk.Button(resistor_frame, text=str(i), command=lambda x=i:self.set_band1(x), width=8, font=FONT1, fg=color[0], bg=color[1])
            button.grid(row=i+2, column=0)
            self.buttons_band1.append(button)

        # === 2nd Band ===

        self.buttons_band2 = []

        for i, color in enumerate(colors_1):
            button = tk.Button(resistor_frame, text=str(i), command=lambda x=i:self.set_band2(x), width=8, font=FONT1, fg=color[0], bg=color[1])
            button.grid(row=i+2, column=1)
            self.buttons_band2.append(button)

        # === 3rd Band ===

        self.buttons_band3 = []

        for i, color in enumerate(colors_1):
            button = tk.Button(resistor_frame, text=str(i), command=lambda x=i:self.set_band3(x), width=8, font=FONT1, fg=color[0], bg=color[1])
            button.grid(row=i+2, column=2)
            self.buttons_band3.append(button)

        # === 4th Band ===

        values = (
            ('x1', 1), ('x10', 10), ('x100', 100),
            ('x1k', 1000), ('x10k', 10000), ('x100k', 100000), 
            ('x1M', 1000000), ('x10M', 10000000), ('x100M', 100000000), 
            ('x0.01', 0.01), ('x0.1M', 0.1)
        )

        self.buttons_band4 = []

        for i, (color, value) in enumerate(zip(colors_2, values)):
            if value:
                button = tk.Button(resistor_frame, text=value[0], command=(lambda x=value[1]:self.set_band4(x)), width=8, font=FONT1, fg=color[0], bg=color[1])
                button.grid(row=i+2, column=3)
                self.buttons_band4.append(button)

        # === 5th Band ===

        values = (
            None, ('1%', 0.01), ('2%', 0.02),
            None, None, ('0.5%', 0.005), ('0.25%', 0.0025), ('0.1%', 0.001),
            ('10%', 0.1), ('5%', 0.05), 
        )

        self.buttons_band5 = []

        for i, (color, value) in enumerate(zip(colors_2, values)):
            if value:
                button = tk.Button(resistor_frame, text=value[0], command=(lambda x=value[0]:self.set_band5(x)), width=8, font=FONT1, fg=color[0], bg=color[1])
                button.grid(row=i+2, column=4)
                self.buttons_band5.append(button)

        # === 6th Band ===

        values = (
            '250ppm/K', '100ppm/K', '50ppm/K', '15ppm/K', '25ppm/K',
        )

        self.buttons_band6 = []

        for i, (color, value) in enumerate(zip(colors_2, values)):
            if value:
                button = tk.Button(resistor_frame, text=value, command=(lambda x=value:self.set_band6(x)), width=8, font=FONT1, fg=color[0], bg=color[1])
                button.grid(row=i+2, column=5)
                self.buttons_band6.append(button)

        # === Indicator Frame ===

        label = tk.Label(indicator_frame, text="Resistor Value", bg='yellow', font=FONT2)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w', padx=10)

        entry = tk.Entry(indicator_frame, width=16, font=FONT2, textvariable=self.var_resistance)
        entry.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=3, columnspan=3)

        label = tk.Label(indicator_frame, text="Tolerance", bg='yellow', font=FONT2)
        label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w', padx=10)

        entry = tk.Entry(indicator_frame, width=16, font=FONT2, textvariable=self.var_tolerance)
        entry.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=3)

        label = tk.Label(indicator_frame, text="Temp. Coefficient", bg='yellow', font=FONT2)
        label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w', padx=10)

        entry = tk.Entry(indicator_frame, width=16, font=FONT2, textvariable=self.var_temp)
        entry.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=5)

        button = tk.Button(indicator_frame, text="QUIT", command=self.quit, width=8, height=2)
        button.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=10)

        button = tk.Button(indicator_frame, text="RESET", command=self.reset, width=8, height=2)
        button.grid(column=2, row=3, pady=10)

        button = tk.Button(indicator_frame, text="HITUNG", command=self.hitung, width=8, height=2)
        button.grid(column=3, row=3, pady=10)


    def enable_band3(self):
        if self.en == 0:
            value = 'normal'
        else:
            value = 'disabled'

        for button in self.buttons_band3:
            button.configure(state=value)
        for button in self.buttons_band5:
            button.configure(state=value)
        for button in self.buttons_band6:
            button.configure(state=value)

    def disable_band3(self):
        if self.dis != 0:
            value = 'normal'
            for button in self.buttons_band3:
                button.configure(state=value)
            for button in self.buttons_band5:
                button.configure(state=value)
            for button in self.buttons_band6:
                button.configure(state=value)

    def enable_band4(self):
        if self.en4 != 1:
            value = 'normal'
            for button in self.buttons_band5:
                button.configure(state=value)

        value = 'disable'
        for button in self.buttons_band3:
            button.configure(state=value)
        for button in self.buttons_band6:
            button.configure(state=value)

    def disable_band4(self):
        if self.dis4 != 1:
            value = 'normal'
            for button in self.buttons_band3:
                button.configure(state=value)
            for button in self.buttons_band5:
                button.configure(state=value)

            value = 'disable'
            for button in self.buttons_band6:
                button.configure(state=value)

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    application = Resistor(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

BTW: If I would keep `IntVar` on list then I could use one `set_band(self, number, value)` instead of `set_band1(self, value)`, `set_band2(self, value)`, etc.

Comment: Mr. Furas thanks to your answer. But how to formatting the value ex:1000 to 1k etc. Also how to change the value v1 from *1000 to *10 if rad.button 3 is active

Comment: to format `1000` to `1k` you have to do it manually - divide by 1000, result convert to string and add char `k`. If you want to covert only values bigger then 1000 then use `if/else` - ie. `if value >= 1000:. Similar when you want to covnert to `1M`. First check `if value >= 1000000` and then divide by `1 000 000`, result convert to string and add char `M`

Comment: if you want to use *1000 instead of *10 when button 3 is avtive then use `if/elif/else` when you calculuate value in `update_labels`

Comment: no.1. im still didnt find out how to convert, no.2 the multiply doesnt change